# How to use the Reverse method of a Stack?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, types, stack

I need to reverse a Stack's order using the `Reverse` method.

But I've tried this and it does not work:

```
    Dim StackObject As New Stack(Of String)
    StackObject.Push("S")
    StackObject.Push("T")
    StackObject.Push("A")
    StackObject.Push("C")
    StackObject.Push("K")

    StackObject = StackObject.Reverse.Cast(Of String)() ' <-- InvalidCastException

    For Each str As String In StackObject
        MsgBox(str)
    Next
```

I wrote this generic function to reverse a Stack but I would like to do it using the `Reverse` method instead of all this unnecesary code:

```
Private Function Reverse_Stack(Of T)(stack As Stack(Of T))

    Dim new_stack As New Stack(Of T)

    While Not stack.Count = 0
        new_stack.Push(stack.Pop)
    End While

    Return new_stack

End Function
```

Comment: Please please please do not use the phrase "does not work". We already know it doesn't work because you are posting here. Post expected behavior and actual behavior. It's so simple. For someone who has as much karma as you have, I'm surprised you failed to do the right thing.

Comment: Uses the phrase "does not work", which should be punishable by death.

Comment: @siride it is obvious that the problem is at the reverse instruction `StackObject = StackObject.Reverse.Cast(Of String)()` you only need to read the title of my question. the debugger throws a casting exception. really people downvotes for nothing.

Comment: Don't make us have to put your code into Visual Studio and debug it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why does `StackObject = StackObject.Reverse().Cast(Of String)()` throw an exception?**

[Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a LINQ extension method that in this case returns an `IEnumerable(Of String)` (which, incidentally, means that `Cast(Of String)` is redundant), so you can't directly assign the result to a variable of type `Stack(Of String)`.

You can use the [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs.aspx) statement to catch this error at compile time instead of at run time.

**So how can I reverse a `Stack(Of T)`?**

Just use the [`Stack(Of T)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, giving it the stack to reverse:

```
Private Function Reverse_Stack(Of T)(stack As Stack(Of T)) As Stack(Of T)
    Return New Stack(Of T)(stack)
End Function
```

You might even make this an extension method, replacing the LINQ `Reverse`:

```
<Extension>
Public Function Reverse(Of T)(stack As Stack(Of T)) As Stack(Of T)
    Return New Stack(Of T)(stack)
End Function
```

Now you can write `StackObject = StackObject.Reverse()` without error.

**How does this work?**

`Stack(Of T).GetEnumerator()` returns the elements in the order that they will be popped from the stack, and the `Stack(Of T)` constructor pushes the elements of the given sequence onto the stack in the order the elements appear in the sequence. Thus the element at the top of the old stack becomes the element at the bottom of the new stack.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou. Really problem is solved with your solution, but i would like to know how to use good the reverse method for a stack, if you could give an example please, if not then no problem.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Unfortunately, as dasblinkenlight explains, `Reverse` is an extension method which returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, not a `Stack(Of T)`. So if you wanted a reversed `Stack(Of T)`, you would need to write something like `New Stack(Of String)(stack.Reverse().Reverse())`, which is kind of pointless, right?

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I've just corrected a typo: I mistakenly wrote `Stack(Of String)` instead of `Stack(Of T)` inside of `Reverse_Stack`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this line

```
StackObject = StackObject.Reverse.Cast(Of String)()
```

is that `Reverse` is an extension method on `IEnumerable(Of T)`. It produces another `IEnumerable(Of T)`. The call of `Cast(Of String)` is unnecessary, because the sequence contains the strings already.

You can use the reversed stack like this:

```
For Each str As String In StackObject.Reverse()
    MsgBox(str)
Next
```

When the stack is used as an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, it produces the items in the reverse order compared to the order of insertion. Therefore, the above loop will produce the letters in the proper insertion sequence, i.e. `S`, `T`, `A`, `C`, `K`.

If you would like to make a new stack out of an existing one, just in reverse order, simply pass your stack to a stack constructor. Because the stack produces values in the reverse insertion order (as mentioned above) the new stack will be the reverse of the original.

Comment: but then how to use the reversem ethod for a Stack? this throws the same casting exception  StackObject = CType(StackObject.Reverse, Stack(Of String))

Comment: @ElektroStudios There is no `Reverse` method built specifically for the stack - it's an *extension* method for `IEnumerable(Of T)`, you cannot cast it to a `Stack(of T)`.